# ¿Como solucionar este error en una consulta?

Tags: php, sql

Cómo solucionar este error?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'AND p.post_date BETWEEN '1607032800' AND '1607122800' ORDER BY
> p.post_puntos ...' at line 1

Es php y la linea del error es esta

```
$query = db_exec(
    array(__FILE__, __LINE__), 'query', 
    'SELECT p.post_id, p.post_category, p.post_title, p.post_puntos, c.c_seo 
    FROM p_posts AS p 
    LEFT JOIN p_categorias AS c ON c.cid = p.post_category  
    WHERE p.post_status = 0 
    AND p.post_category !='.$tsCore->settings['ccrap'].' 
    AND p.post_date BETWEEN \''.$date['start'].'\' 
    AND \''.$date['end'].'\' 
    ORDER BY p.post_puntos DESC LIMIT 15'
);
```

Y esto lo que sale en el mensaje

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.post_category, p.post_title, p.post_puntos, c.c_seo 
FROM p_posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN p_categorias AS c ON c.cid = p.post_category 
WHERE p.post_status = 0 
AND p.post_category != AND p.post_date BETWEEN '1607032800' AND '1607122800' 
ORDER BY p.post_puntos DESC LIMIT 15
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$tsCore->settings['ccrap']` esta entregando un valor vacio, por ello la consulta se invalida en `!= {vacio} AND ...`

```
AND p.post_category != AND p.post_date BETWEEN '1607032800' AND '1607122800'
```

Si dicho valor es texto y puede efectivamente estar vacio, debes encerrar el valor entre comillas:

```
AND p.post_category !=\''.$tsCore->settings['ccrap'].'\'
```

En caso de que no se suponga que venga vacio, revisa de donde viene el valor para ver porqué está vacio.